# C# SQL Update query wont work

Tags: c#, sql

```
SqlCommand insertCoins = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Table] SET coins = 
@rouletteCoins 
WHERE steamid = @userid", cnn);
insertCoins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rouletteCoins", coins);
insertCoins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", info);
insertCoins.ExecuteScalar();
```

Trying to send a basic query to the database, it works with insert and select but not with update. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Change the ExecuteScalar to ExecuteNonQuery(). ExecuteNonQuery does return the number of rows affected

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery()` to be used

Comment: When you have a problem you need to detail what the problem is.... what is happening that you don't expect? do you have an error message? In some cases you might get lucky and someone will know the answer without this information, but you should include the information none the less

Comment: Then it sounds like there's no steamid in the database that matches `info`. Use the debugger to confirm what the values are. Try the query in your db management tool of choice with the same values and see if you get the same results. And please...pick a better name for your table than `Table`. That's just confusing. It's like calling a variable `variable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ExecuteNonQuery() instead of ExecuteScalar(). Use this (ExecuteNonQuery) for insert, update and delete statements.